# findViewById returns null when used in library module

Tags: android, android-library, findviewbyid

I have a library module where I am trying to get view using `findViewByID` using activity instance. I also tried doing the same by using the rootView. The code I have used is as following.

```
System.out.println("activity instance: "+mActivity.findViewById(hexid));
System.out.println("using root view: "+rootView.findViewById(hexid));
```

When I am adding directly in project it is working fine and the same code returns a corresponding view. Problem occurs when I am making `.aar` file of library module and add it as dependency to my project the same code is not working and returns `null`.

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Did you mark hexid param as @IdRes ?

Comment: it is the int value of id.

Comment: Apparently It was fools mistake, The id I was referring to was incorrect that's why view was being returned null.